# How to display an object's properties as controls in a single cell item of a TreeView in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx, data-binding, combobox, treeview, controls

Is it possible to represent a Node's properties by a Label, a ComboBox (or more controls) in a TreeView's cell item?
I would like to display the name of the node, a selected item (and more controls (e.g. Checkboxes) if possible) in each treeview cell.
Is it possible to do this?

According to Oracle's tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm) the CheckBoxTreeCell, ChoiceBoxTreeCell, ComboBoxTreeCell, TextFieldTreeCell classes can be used for similar purposes, but I can't figure out how to use many of those in single cell, or how to make an editable template for the cells.

My model is similar to this:

```
public enum Options {
    Option1, Option2, ... OptionN;
}

// I want to use this Node class as a TreeItem
public class Node {

    private Node parentNode;
    private List<Node> childNodes;

    // Data to be displayed and edited by using only the tree
    private String name;            // displayed as Label
    private Options selectedOption; // displayed as ComboBox
    // private boolean valid;       // displayed as Checkbox
    // these properties possibly should be JavaFX's ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty etc.

    // ...
}
```

What I want to show would be similar to this:

```
Node0 [ComboBox: (selectedOption = Options.OptionI)]
|-- Node1 [ComboBox: (selectedOption = Options.OptionJ)]
|   |-- Node11 [ComboBox: (selectedOption = Options.OptionK)]
|-- Node2 [ComboBox: (selectedOption = Options.OptionK)]
    |-- Node21 [ComboBox: (selectedOption = Options.OptionL)]
    |-- Node22 [ComboBox: (selectedOption = Options.OptionJ)]
```

... where the user can set the Node's properties by editing the tree's elements.
What approach should I use to achieve this functionality?

Sorry if that's a basic question, I have just started to learn JavaFx.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2229/tableview/8814/customizing-tablecell-look-depending-on-item

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using `TreeTableView`. If that `Control` does not suit your needs however you can use a custom `TreeCell`:

```
TreeView<Node> treeView = ...
treeView.setCellFactory(t -> new TreeCell<Node>() {

    private final ComboBox<Options> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Options.values()));
    private final CheckBox valid = new CheckBox("valid");
    private final VBox container = new VBox(comboBox, valid); // todo: add more controls for other properties

    private boolean swapping;

    {
        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!swapping) {
                 getItem().setSelectedOption(newValue);
            }
        });
        valid.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!swapping) {
                 getItem().setValid(newValue);
            }
        });

        // todo: listeners to other controls...

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.BOTTOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Node item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem();
        if (empty) {
            setText("");
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.getName());
            setGraphic(container);
            swapping = true;

            comboBox.setValue(item.getSelectedOption());
            valid.setSelected(item.isValid());
            // todo: initialize other nodes with item values

            swapping = false;
        }
    }
});
```